# DH Matrix to homogeneous transformation matrix for each joint

Tags: kinematics, joint, dh-parameters

Given a DH matrix for a set of joints, how would you convert the data into homogeneous transformation matrices for each joint? I've looked online, but can't find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Slide 34 of [University of Sydney Experimental Robotics MTRX4700](http://www.aeromech.usyd.edu.au/MTRX4700/Course_Documents/material/lectures/L2_Kinematics_Dynamics_2013.pdf)

Thumbnail image:
[image: DH Parameter transformation]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer posted by Gouda, I would like to point out that there are different versions of D-H parameter convention. Gotta be careful which one you refer to. Also, in the computation, only 2 cylindrical motions are needed to define the homogeneous matrix, meaning you can combine the translation and rotation along the same axis:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{\theta_i} & -s_{\theta_i} & 0 & 0 \\
s_{\theta_i} & c_{\theta_i} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & d_i\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & a_i\\
0 & c_{\alpha_i} & -s_{\alpha_i} & 0 \\
0 & s_{\alpha_i} & c_{\alpha_i} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In other words, DH paramters work as if it is a 4-DoF serial robot with two cylindrical joints. This is not a nice way to parameterize the relative location of ith joint axis w.r.t. (i-1)th (singularity exists). Multiplying with four matrices is just a waster of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this paper: "[Lipkin 2005: A Note on Denavit-Hartenberg Notation in Robotics](http://profesores.usfq.edu.ec/laurents/IME440/DETC2005-85460_DenavitHartenberg.pdf)".  It explains the **3** main DH parameter conventions and how they differ.